ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC : get session and cookies in view
Browser>Application>Cookies

I am attempting to create session and cookies in a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project.
When I debug the project locally on my PC, the session and cookies are working as expected, but when deploy to server, the session seems not able to be retrieved in the view (.cshtml), and cookies looked like above.
I am wondering why the cookies name kept showing "SameSite" and values were "None".

That's because the frontend can't get the session. Because session is in backend.

Hii, i am a beginner to this, but i am using Razor view which allow embedding backend code. What I plan to do is to identify if session is set, and dynamically generate the html content to the user. Tested locally and it works well but once deployed it goes wrong. All the cookies name are set to “SameSite” and Value=“None” when I inspect in browser’s devtool

For this kind of issue, you need check below settings.

Check your server environment and application setup.  Like: If you are using a load balancer or reverse proxy, ensure that it is configured to handle cookies correctly and not stripping attributes like SameSite.

I suggest you could re-check your application makeup, to make sure you don't have the specific settings for the session, like set the session stored inside some specific database or else.

Please ensure the Https has been enabled, if your cookie contains the Secure attribute, ensure your site is running over HTTPS. The Secure attribute tells the browser to send cookies only over secure channels.

Please make sure your codes have firstly set the session in somewhere and get it from the view to see if the session is working well or not. For some condition, the session is null if you don't store the value inside it.



See the following link:
Adding a new cookie in ASP.NET Core 6
The "Session" you mentioned is ambiguous.
If you mean "Client-Side Session", you must deal with cookie settings, but if you mean "Server-Side Session", you must add it in the Service section.
It is also good to see the following link:
Session not working in asp.net core 6.0 when tring to access it on the view
